# Is there a way to align right for sequential elements according to the end of the first line in HTML?

Tags: html, css

[image]

I need to align this text right to left but not from the farthest point on the page and am unsure of how to do so using the end of the first line as the reference point to start the text align right.

Answer (score 4):

```css
.wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>longest line of text</div>
  <div>line of text</div>
  <div>line of text</div>
</div>
```

Can't test at the moment but that should be what you're looking for. Inline block wrapper "shrinks" to size of content which is the widest block, the child block elements will naturally expand to be the width of the parent.

Comment: Thank you so much, that did the trick and allowed me to learn a little bit more about the differences between display inline, display block and display inline-block.

Comment: @JosephCarrier if you're just getting started with CSS, I highly recommend "playing around" with all of the display and position properties, and look into box-sizing (I set everything to border-box by default). Getting a feel for those will allow you to solve most layouts easily.

Comment: @JosephCarrier And don't forget to hit "accept" on the answer if it solves your question!